# Express Laplace transform of voltage across a capacitor in terms of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, laplace-transform

In [Charge Tunneling Rates in Ultrasmall Junctions](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0508728#) section 2.1, the authors consider the problem of charge relaxation in a simple circuit shown in Figure A.
The implicitly use an assumption made about the respresentation of voltage in the Laplace domain that I do not understand.
To pose the question, let us first lay out the point of the calculation.

[image]
**Figure A:** A capacitor coupled to an arbitrary impedance $\tilde{Z}(\omega)$ and a dc voltage source $V$.

Denote the equilibrium charge across the capacitor is $Q_e$.
At time $t=0$ we drop some extra charge on the capacitor, making the total capacitor charge $Q_0$.
We'd like to solve for the time dependent charge $Q(t)$ on the capacitor.

From the definition of impedance we have
$$\hat{V}(p) = \hat{Z}(p) \hat{I}(p)$$
where $V$ is voltage, $Z$ is impedance, and $I$ is current.
Using the derivative rule for Laplace transforms (straightforward algebra/calculus), we find
$$\hat{I}(p) = p \hat{Q}(p) - Q_0$$
which gives us
$$\hat{V}(p) = \hat{Z}(p)(p\hat{Q}(p) - Q_0) \, .$$

To finish solving the problem, we need to express $\hat{V}$ in terms of $\hat{Q}$.
In the paper Equation (9), the authors simply write
$$\frac{Q_e}{pC} = \frac{\hat{Q}(p)}{C} + \hat{Z}(p)(p \hat{Q}(p) - Q_0)\ \, .$$
which *implies* that
$$\hat{V}(p) = \frac{Q_e}{pC} - \frac{\hat{Q}(p)}{C} \, , \tag{$\star$}$$
but I don't understand why that's the case.

Why is equation $(\star)$ correct?
Does it come from some considerations of the boundary conditions or some other physical reasoning, or from a simple mathematical consideration?

---

In this question, $\tilde{x}$ indicates a Fourier transform defined as $$\tilde{x}(\omega) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) \exp(-i \omega t) \, dt$$ and $\hat{x}(p)$ indicates a Laplace transform defined as $$\hat{x}(p) \equiv \int_0^\infty x(t) \exp(-pt) \, dt \, .$$

With this Fourier convention:

- A causal linear response function $Z$ has $Z(t<0)=0$.
- The Fourier and Laplace transforms are related by $\hat{x}(p) = \tilde{x}(-ip)$ (again assuming causal functions).

Comment: This seems to be an *exercise* so I have added the appropriate tag. But I am wondering how you justify this as a conceptual question, ie not *off topic*? It seems to me that you are asking for someone to point out the error in your calculation, which I understand to make the question *off topic*.

Comment: @sammygerbil I haven't provided any work to be checked. I'm specifically asking why, conceptually, it makes sense to write $\hat{V}(p) = Q_e/pC - \hat{Q}(p)/C$.

Comment: Just because you add the word *conceptually* to a question does not make it a conceptual question. The answer given by Skyler is not conceptual, it is a calculation. He has interpreted your question as "How do I obtain equation $(*)$?" ... What kind of *conceptual* answer would satisfy you?

Comment: @sammygerbil The qualities of a particular answer doesn't dictate the on-topicness of a question. The kind of conceptual answer that would satisfy me is to explain where the equation comes from. Is it from boundary conditions? Is it something about Kirchoff's laws? I think if you read the question more closely you'll see that what I'm asking is about a very specific simple expression, so simple in fact that no calculation is needed, only a better conceptual understanding.

Comment: Perhaps you could upload the relevant section of the paper? Does the author write equation (∗) as an obvious starting point, or as the result of a calculation? Your own question suggests that it should come as the last step of the calculation. But I appreciate that it might be possible to recognise it as the difference of two meaningful voltages, and that is the explanation you are asking for - in which case the preamble is unnecessary and misleading. (BTW what is $Q_e$? Is that the same as $Q_0$?)

Comment: This question is [discussed on Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9686/44126).

Comment: @sammygerbil You should probably read my response to the meta post. The gist is that I think your edit is inappropriate. Specifically, two issues: (1) this question doesn't deserve the tag, which is discussed by the meta post, and (2) you applied quote formatting to something which is not a quote.

Comment: @sammygerbil as DavidZ noted, the use of quote formatting was unjustified, as was the homework tag, so I rolled it back.

Comment: I apologise for incorrectly using the quote format. I did not realise that it is intended only for quotes rather than to emphasize the problem that you are attempting to solve. But I still disagree about the tag, and will respond in detail to DavidZ's answer in Meta.

Comment: 1. Why did you define a Fourier transform as $\tilde{x}$ if you never use one as far as I can see? 2. There seem to be some assumptions missing. Your $Q_0$ is an arbitrary input, but for your eq. ($\star$) to follow from your equation before that, $Q_0$ *has* to be related to $Z(p),C$ and $Q_e$, which are fixed properties of the circuit. But this is impossible, an arbitrary input to the situation cannot be a function of fixed parameters of the situation.

Comment: @sammygerbil Link to arXiv paper added. I think I've clarified the question. Please comment if you still think it's homework. Also regarding your comment: *"BTW what is $Q_e$?"* That was clearly stated at the beginning of the post and is still stated clearly in the recent edit (v5). Please read the question before passing judgement that it's against the homework policy.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. To help readers understand the question! Impedances are implicitly Fourier transforms of a time domain linear response kernel, so I thought it would be good to explain the relation to the Laplace transforms used by the authors. 2. I don't understand. Hit me up in chat.

Comment: Ah, your edit has explained what I wanted to know. But now, if we look at this in the time domain, is that not merely $V(t) = \frac{Q_e}{C}\theta(t) - \frac{Q(t)}{C}$, which is true by definition of capacitance (if you turn the equilibrium charge on at $t=0$ and define $Q(t)$ suitably)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't understand the sign.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here:

1. Your $Q_0$ is *not* the total charge on the capacitor, but the *added* charge to $Q_e$. The voltage $V(p)$ is the voltage across the rest of the circuit. We can see this from your equation
   $$ \hat{I}(p) = p\hat{Q}(p) - Q_0$$
   and putting in the equilibrium configuration $Q(t) = Q_e\theta(t)$ where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside function that turns the equilibrium charge on at $t=0$. The transforms are $\hat{I}(p) = Q_e$ and $\hat{Q}(p) = Q_e/p$, implying $Q_0 = 0$ in equilibrium. This happens because the value $\theta(0)$ is a convention that can be *anything* from $0$ to $1$, and the implicit convention of this Laplace transform is that it is $0$.

   Note that the current computed as $\hat{I}(p)$ has a sign problem: You can't exactly put a charge of $Q_0$ onto a capacitor, you must decide *on which of the plates* you put it. If you *increase* the charge on the plate that is already charged in the equilibrium configuration, then the current will flow *opposite* to the current when the capacitor was charged. So, if $Q_0$ denotes putting *more* positive charge on the already positively charged plate, the voltage *across the rest of the circuit* will be $V(t) = \frac{Q_e}{C}\theta(t) - \frac{Q(t)}{C}$, where $Q(0) = Q_0$.
2. Your $Q_0$ is the total charge on the capacitor, and the voltage you are computing is the voltage *across the impedance*. Then, by Kirchhoff's laws, we have
   $$ V+V_C+V_0 = 0,$$
   where $V_C = Q(t)/C$ is the voltage on the capacitor and $V_0 = -Q_e/C$ is the contant voltage (not causally turned on this time!) across the DC voltage source. The latter equation only holds if the impedance has neglegible capacitance, since then we have $V = 0$ in equilibrium where $I=0$ and $Z$ is non-singular.

Comment: Honestly, to me it seems that the authors just made a big mess with the Laplace transform. They want to arrive at the equation (10), $Q(t) = Q_e+(Q_0-Q_e)R(t)$, where the charge is expressed as a function of the initial charge $Q_0$ on the capacitor and on the equilibrium value $Q_e$, which is the _final_ charge on the capacitor. But since the Laplace transform does not allow an immediate writing of an equation as a function of the final value, they wrote a wrong argument. There's also no need to consider $V$ and $Q_e$ at all in the analysis of the relaxation time: it's a linear circuit!

Answer (score -1):

Starting with:
$$\hat{V}(p) = \hat{Z}(p)(p\hat{Q}(p) - Q_0) \, .$$

and using our knowledge of ideal capacitors undergoing reactive impedance (a purely imaginary term for impedence) such that:

$$\hat{Z}(\omega)=\frac{1}{i\omega C}=\hat{Z}(p)=\frac{1}{pC}$$

if we distribute the impedence we get 
$$\hat{V}(p) = (\frac{p\hat{Q}(p)}{pC} - \frac{Q_0}{pC}) \, .$$

but to do this division we are dividing by a complex number (namely $0 + i\omega t$), meaning we should multiply both terms by it's complex conjugate $0 - i\omega t$ or $p*=-p$ leading to

$$\hat{V}(p) = (\frac{|p^2|\hat{Q}(p)}{|p^2|C} - \frac{p^*Q_0}{|p^2|C})$$

With $\frac{p^*}{|p^2|} being \frac{i}{i^2}\frac{|\omega|}{|\omega|^2}=\frac{-i}{w}$
Which leads to the result:
$$\hat{V}(p) =  \frac{\hat{Q}(p)}{C} \ - \frac{Q_e}{|p|C}  \tag{$\star$}$$

Which could be written as 
$$\hat{V}(p) =  \frac{\hat{Q}(p)}{C} \ + \frac{Q_e}{pC}  \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: See diagram. $Z$ is not the impedance of the capacitor.

Comment: hmm...noted, what is known about $Z$ then?

Comment: It's an impedance, but that is wholly irrelevant to understanding why $\hat{V}(p)=Q_e/pC - \hat{Q}(p)/C$.

Comment: How does the initial condition $Q_0$ morph into the circuit property $Q_e$ in this derivation?